# Kth Ancestor of a Tree Node Challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, dynamic-programming

The challenge is as follows:

You are given a tree with n nodes numbered from 0 to n-1 in the form of a
parent array where parent[i] is the parent of node i. The root of the tree
is node 0.

Implement the function getKthAncestor(int node, int k) to return the k-th
ancestor of the given node. If there is no such ancestor, return -1.

The k-th ancestor of a tree node is the k-th node in the path from that
node to the root.

Example:

Input:

```
["TreeAncestor","getKthAncestor","getKthAncestor","getKthAncestor"]
[[7,[-1,0,0,1,1,2,2]],[3,1],[5,2],[6,3]]
```

Output:

```
[null,1,0,-1]
```

Explanation:

```
TreeAncestor treeAncestor = new TreeAncestor(7, [-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]);

treeAncestor.getKthAncestor(3, 1);  // returns 1 which is the parent of 3
treeAncestor.getKthAncestor(5, 2);  // returns 0 which is the grandparent of 5
treeAncestor.getKthAncestor(6, 3);  // returns -1 because there is no such ancestor
```

Constraints:

```
1 <= k <= n <= 5*10^4
parent[0] == -1 indicating that 0 is the root node.
0 <= parent[i] < n for all 0 < i < n
0 <= node < n
There will be at most 5*10^4 queries.
```

and I'm having difficulty understanding a person's solution to this. Would anyone be nice as to explain how his optimal solution works? This is a new challenge, in the recent leetcode contest, and there is no duplicate for it.

```py
class TreeAncestor(object):

    def __init__(self, n, parent):
        self.pars = [parent]
        self.n = n
        for k in range(17):
            row = []
            for i in range(n):
                p = self.pars[-1][i]
                if p != -1:
                    p = self.pars[-1][p]
                row.append(p)
            self.pars.append(row)


    def getKthAncestor(self, node, k):
        """
        :type node: int
        :type k: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        i = 0
        while k:
            if node == -1: break
            if (k&1):
                node = self.pars[i][node]
            i += 1
            k >>= 1
        return node
```

Comment: This is a well known problem, and the solution uses sparse table and binary lifting, [an example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-ancestor-of-a-node-in-an-n-ary-tree-using-binary-lifting-technique/)

Answer (score 2):

Wow. That's a cool solution.

The solution is based on two ideas:

- Building a matrix of ancestors during construction time (`self.pars`).
- Decomposing the ancestor graph to chain to steps of size 1, 2, 4, 8, etc (2^n).

`self.pars` is a matrix where row number `n` represents the 2^n ancestor of the i-th element in the row (n starting with 0). For example, in row #3 we'll have the 8th ancestor of all the elements in the nodes in the tree.

Then at query time, the algorithm decomposes the request to get the k-th ancestor of a node to a series of log(k) steps. Each step is a digit in the binary representation of k.

For example, consider k=6. The binary representation of 9 is 1-1-0:

- Digit 0 (The last one) is 0, so do nothing.
- Digit 1 is 1. 2^1 is 2, so get the 2nd ancestor of the node we're looking at.
- Digit 2 is also 1. 2^2 is 4, so get the 4th ancestor of the current node.

And we're done - in 3 steps, we went all the way to the target node.

Comment: I'd like to add a little explanation for the part that took me some time (and some print statements too) to understand, the `self.pars` build process. There is no apparent series of steps 1,2,4,8. The parent list allows to look up the parent, i.e. to go 1 step in the path. If we apply the list to itself, we will have a list of 2 steps (1+1). But when we do the same with the new list, we will have not 3, but 4 steps (2+2). Then 4+4 etc.

Comment: MahdeenSkyYT - does this answer your question?